# SFINAE and template function instantiation: Why a template argument cannot be deduced when used in function arguments with a SFINAE-enabled type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-argument-deduction

I was experimenting with SFINAE these days, and something puzzles me. Why `my_type_a` cannot be deduced in `my_function`'s instantiation?

```
class my_type_a {};

template <typename T>
class my_common_type {
public:
    constexpr static const bool valid = false;
};

template <>
class my_common_type<my_type_a> {
public:
    constexpr static const bool valid = true;
    using type = my_type_a;
};

template <typename T> using my_common_type_t = typename my_common_type<T>::type;

template <typename T, typename V>
void my_function(my_common_type_t<T> my_cvalue, V my_value) {}

int main(void) {
    my_function(my_type_a(), 1.0);
}
```

G++ gives me this:

```
/home/flisboac/test-template-template-arg-subst.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/flisboac/test-template-template-arg-subst.cpp:21:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘my_function(my_type_a, double)’
  my_function(my_type_a(), 1.0);
                              ^
/home/flisboac/test-template-template-arg-subst.cpp:18:6: note: candidate: template<class T, class V> void my_function(my_common_type_t<T>, V)
 void my_function(my_common_type_t<T> my_type, V my_value) {}
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/flisboac/test-template-template-arg-subst.cpp:18:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/flisboac/test-template-template-arg-subst.cpp:21:30: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
  my_function(my_type_a(), 1.0);
                              ^
```

What I expected was that, when calling `my_function` as I did in `main`, `T` would be deduced to the type of the function's first argument, and that type would be used in the function's instantiation. But it seems that `my_common_type_t<T>` is instantiated before the function, but even then, the type of `my_cvalue` would become `my_type_a` anyways, so I cannot see why this wouldn't work...

Is there a different way to do this? Should I just avoid two (or more) levels of template indirection?

Comment: In `my_common_type<T>::type`, `T` is in [non-deduced context](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts). You expect the compiler to instantiate `my_common_type` with every possible type `T`, in hopes that, for exactly one of them, `my_common_type<T>::type` comes out to be compatible with `my_type_a`; or else engage in theorem proving exercise to try and find such a type analytically. The compiler does neither.

Comment: @Igor I understand that the Rule 1 (from the link you provided) certainly matches my example. However, why is it not clear that `T` is not necessarily `my_type_a`? If `my_common_type<T>` was instantiated before instantiating `my_function`, the type would be either `my_type_a` or nothing (and therefore the function would be eliminated through SFINAE). If it was instead instantiated during or after, the compiler would have the information of `my_common_type<my_type_a>` as a candidate (and because of that, `T = my_type_a`), would it not?

Comment: *"why is it not clear"* That's the theorem-proving exercise I was talking about. "Clear" here means "can be proven from available facts". And perhaps it can be - but the compiler is not required to possess this kind of reasoning engine.

Comment: I thought that information could be obtained from the call site. But perhaps I'm considering things from the wrong perspective. I think I understood the problem here, but I'm having a hard time trying to come up with a clear answer. `my_function` receives a value of type `my_common_type<T>::type` in argument `my_cvalue`, and `T` is not used anywhere else. What I'm passing to the function is a value of `my_type_a`, that is concrete. `my_common_type<T>::type` is still unknown, because `::type` depends on the template substitution, that in turn depends on `T`, that is yet not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, consider this:

```
template <>
struct my_common_type<int> {
    constexpr static const bool valid = true;
    using type = my_type_a;
};

template <>
struct my_common_type<double> {
    constexpr static const bool valid = true;
    using type = my_type_a;
};

// ...

int main(void) {
    my_function(my_type_a{}, 1.0);
}
```

Does the compiler chooses `my_common_type<int>` or `my_common_type<double>`?

If the language would permit deduction in you case, it would have to match what `T` would be in `my_common_type<T>::type` in order to yield the exact type you send to the function parameter. Obviously, it's not only impossible, but with my example above, it may have multiple choices!

Fortunately, there is a way to tell the compiler that `my_common_type<T>` will always yield to `T`. The basics of the trick is this:

```
template<typename T>
using test_t = T;

template<typename T>
void call(test_t<T>) {}

int main() {
    call(1);
}
```

What is `T` deduces to? `int`, easy! The compiler is happy with this kind of match. Also, since `test_t` cannot be specialized, `test_t<soxething>` is known to only be `something`.

Also, this is working too with multiple levels of aliases:

```
template<typename T>
using test_t = T;

template<typename T>
using test2_t = test_t<T>;

template<typename T>
void call(test2_t<T>) {}

int main() {
    call(1); // will also work
}
```

We can apply this to your case, but we will need some tool:

```
template<typename T, typename...>
using first_t = T;
```

This is the same easy match as above, but we can also send some argument that will not be used. We will make sfinae in this unused pack.

Now, rewrite `my_common_type_t` to still be an easy match, whilst adding the constraint in the unused pack:

```
template <typename T>
using my_common_type_t = first_t<T, typename my_common_type<T>::type>;
```

Note that this is also working:

```
template <typename T>
using my_common_type_t = first_t<T, std::enable_if_t<my_common_type<T>::valid>>;
```

Now deduction will happen as expected! <kbd>[Live (GCC)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd024d40de00c3ca)</kbd> <kbd>[Live (Clang)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c15238f5093c15da)</kbd>

Note that this trick will only work with C++14, as sfinae in this case (dropped parameters) is only guaranteed to happen since C++14.

Also note that you should either use `struct` for your trait, or use `public:` to make the member `my_common_type<T>::type` public, or else GCC will output a bogus error.

Comment: Wow, that's certainly a good option, and it answers my question! But my case is a bit more complicated that that, because `my_common_type<T>::type` is selected depending on the template parameters. In other words, it's not just a matter of enabling.  Also, I thought the compiler would first look at the function call site and see that `T` is `my_type_a`, regardless of `my_common_type`'s specializations. Also also, I think neither `my_common_type<int>` nor `my_common_type<double>` would be selected because none of them are specializations of `my_common_type<T>` for `T = my_type_a`.

Comment: I wanted to update my question, but your answer is so useful that I feel like making another question to answer my specific problem.

Comment: @FlávioLisbôa Thanks! Always happy to help. Asking another question would be the proper way to do it in this site indeed.